# Hi All, I'm trying to copy paste data from Macro excel file to another Excel file but the thing is that I want to copy data to diff. cell cordinates

Tags: python-3.x, excel, logic, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl library here.

Q1. How should I tweak it so that it can take macro file data for File 1?

Q2. how to copy paste this data in different cells (Than what is specified in the "i" & "j" variables)

In the below code, I am able to copy paste cells of file 1 in the same cell locations for file 2 Which is = 4 rows (row numbers- 1 to 4) having 4 columns (Column numbers- B to E)

However, I want to paste my data in file 2 which is in the 4 rows (Row number 8 to 11) & columns (Column numbers- G to J)

Pls see below the code I'm using currently-

```
import openpyxl as xl

#Copy from file1
file1="D:\\Python Excel copy-paste\\New Excel\\D1.xlsx"
wb1=xl.load_workbook(file1)
ws1=wb1["data"]

#paste to file 2
file2="D:\\Python Excel copy-paste\\New Excel\\D2.xlsx"
wb2=xl.load_workbook(file2)
ws2=wb2["here"]

for i in range(1,5):
    for j in range(2,6):
        
        ws2.cell(row=i,column=j).value=ws1.cell(row=i,column=j).value
                
wb2.save(file2)
```

It is pasting data in the same cells of file 2, I want to paste this data in different cells of file 2. Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make a shift from the origin coordinates.

try this :

```
for i in range(1,5):
    for j in range(2,6):
        ws2.cell(row=i+4,column=j+4).value=ws1.cell(row=i,column=j).value
```